# An explicit description of topology over completion of topological groups

Tags: general-topology, formal-completions

Take $G$ an abelian topological group additively written. Now, following the Atiyah Macdonald, I define its completion as the set of Cauchy sequences quotiented for the usual equivalent relation. Now, in the Atiyah Macdonald they doesn't explicit the topology so I've tried to descrive the neighborhoods of the origin.

Take $U$ an neighborhood of $0$ in $G$ and define $\hat{U}$ as the Cauchy sequences which (have a representant such that) are definitively in $U$. In other terms: the set in  $\hat{G}$ of class of Cauchy sequences $(x_n)$ such that for $n$ sufficiently great $x_n \in U$.

Is this right?

Is this the topology induced by the map $\phi : G \rightarrow \hat{G}$ which send $g$ in the constant sequence $(g)$? If yes, why?

Comment: Is $G$ Abelian?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Comment: Consider that primary example: $G = \Bbb Q$ under addition. Then the completion of $G$ is $\Bbb R$. You will not only see that your concept does indeed generate the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ from that of $\Bbb Q$, and it may help you to see why it makes sense. For your other question, assuming that by "the topology induced", you mean the finest topology on $\hat G$ for which $\phi$ is continuous, note that $\phi^{-1}((-\pi,\pi)) = \phi^{-1}([-\pi,\pi])$.

Comment: Thinking about the first question and the example that you suggest (which is the same that I had in mind) I think that it works. Take an interval $I$ in the set of real number, now each point in $I$ is limit of a series of rational numbers which belong to preimage of $I$ by $\phi$. Is right? One doubt is that I use, for my intuition, the injectivity of $\phi$ that is equivalent to require that the space is Haussdorff. So I could rewrite the question asking if the example of $\mathbb{Q}$ is right and if this is the right approach in every case.

Comment: In $\hat U$ you want sequences such that all the members of their eq. class are eventually in $U$ rather than having one such representative, otherwise you run into problems with sequences converging to a point on the boundary of U from inside vs from outside

Comment: Why is that a problem? Sorry, maybe is trivial but now I don't figure it